# Не удается подключиться к базе данных через RedBeen

Tags: php

Ошибка:

> Parse error: in C:\OSPanel\domains\localhost\php\libs\rb.php on line 338"

Пробовал менять версию PHP на 7, но не помогло.

```
<?php require_once 'folder/rb.php'; R::setup(
 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=primo','root', '' );
```

Comment: Посмотрите строку в файле, в котором ошибка. Обновите RedBean наконец.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нужно было обновить версию и всё.